# DataTables search on button click instead of typing in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I would to know if it is possible to move the search function out of an `input` for a table modified by `DataTables`. Currently I have a custom input that executes this function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#staffTable').DataTable();
        $('#searchNameField').keyup(function () {
            oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
    })
</script>
```

the input looks like so:

```
<label for="searchNameField" class="col col-form-label">Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-11">
    <input type="text" class="form-control ml-0 pl-2" id="searchNameField"
            placeholder="Name" autofocus/>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is move this to a button. What I thought might be possible is the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#staffTable').DataTable();
        $('#searchButton').click(function () {
            oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
    })
</script>
```

with the button looking like so:

```
<button id="searchButton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="width: 150px">
    <i class="fa fa-search">
        Search
    </i>
</button>
```

however when I click on the button this does not work. In typing this question I have realised that this is probably because when I click the button, it does not know where to get the filter text from to actually filter the table.

Is there a way I can have a button click that references the input, that then goes and filters the table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, you need to redefine `$(this)`, which now refers to the button, not the search box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#staffTable').DataTable();
    $('#searchButton').click(function () {
        oTable.search($("#searchNameField").val()).draw();
    });

    // EDIT: Capture enter press as well
    $("#searchNameField").keypress(function(e) {
        // You can use $(this) here, since this once again refers to your text input            
        if(e.which === 13) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submit
            oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect James thanks. Is there a way that I can use the enter press when the user is inside the `#searchNameField` to also fire this function?

Comment: Interestingly that does perform the search but it also refreshes the page at the same time..

Comment: That typically means it's inside a form that captures the enter press and submits. Edit incoming.

Comment: Give that a shot, @CBreeze

Comment: Fantastic. I'll make sure to have a look at how this works in more detail and also accept this answer when I am able to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

```
let datatable = $('#reg_users').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'serverMethod': 'GET',  
    'ajax': { 'url':'<?=$url?>adminActions.php?action=FETCH_USERS' },
    'columns': [ 
        { data: 'index' }, 
        { data: 'user_registered' }, 
        { data: 'full_name' },
        { data: 'email_address' },
    ],
    search: {
        return: true
    } 
}); 

$("#reg_users_filter").append(`<button id="searchbtn">Search</button>`);

$("#searchbtn").click(e =>{  
        datatable.search($('#reg_users_filter input').val()).draw(); 
});
```